# Extract data from website in a loop (changing date) to Sheet

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

First off, I'm completely new to VBA and want to build a weather statistic in Excel. Help is much appreciated!

For this I need data from multiple websites which include the information of the messured temperature, the weather station and the time.

With some VBA information I found on the internet I have so far written a code, which delivers me the needed information for one website in the immediate window only.

Which looks like this:

```
7.4°C | Wien-Mariabrunn (225m) | 14:00
7.6°C | Wien-Hohe Warte (198m) | 14:00
7.6°C | Wien-Unterlaa (200m) | 14:00
7.7°C | Wien-Schwechat (183m) | 14:00
7.8°C | Wien-Donaufeld (160m) | 14:00
8.1°C | Grossenzersdorf (154m) | 14:00
8.2°C | Wien-City (177m) | 14:00
```

---

```
Dim xmlReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim Temps1 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim temps2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Temp As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

xmlReq.Open "GET", "https://kachelmannwetter.com/at/messwerte/wien/temperatur/20190101-1300z.html", False
xmlReq.send

If xmlReq.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & xmlReq.Status & " - " & xmlReq.statusText
    Exit Sub
End If

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = xmlReq.responseText

Set Temps1 = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("ap o o-1 o-tmp-5")
Set temps2 = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("ap o o-1 o-tmp-1")

For Each Temp In Temps1
    Debug.Print Temp.Title
Next Temp

For Each Temp In temps2
    Debug.Print Temp.Title
Next Temp
```

First problem I have, is that I have no idea how to put this information into a sheet or cells.

The second problem is, that I need the same data from multiple websites from a startdate to enddate.
The website I used in this example-code is `https://kachelmannwetter.com/at/messwerte/wien/temperatur/20190101-1300z.html`. At the end you can find the date, in this example "20190101" & the time "1300".
So for this I need some kind of loop.

So at the end I need a worksheet with column A with the date, column B with the time and column C with the data (for each date & time).

I hope this was somehow understandable and I am very thankful for any help.

Comment: You nees to give a reference to a cell instead of debug print. Like `thisworkbook.worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")=Temp.Title`

Comment: Some good tutorials on loops can be found here; https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried it and I really get data to the active worksheet. But the problem is, that there is just the last line from my example from above: 8.2°C | Wien-City (177m) | 14:00

Comment: You will have to start looping at that point. Next getxml request into the next row. For easy looping you can use `.Cells(2,1)` to reference A2 for example. This makes looping easy as you can use numbers.

Comment: Without the other urls we have no idea whether your current method will work across pages. It would be helpful to show expected output (for the combined output of the various sites). Does all info reside in every page?

Comment: @Luuklag: I'm really sorry, but I have no idea how to get the request into the next row.

Comment: The website in my example is "https://kachelmannwetter.com/at/messwerte/wien/temperatur/20190101-1300z.html" - the next page would be ".../20190101-1400z.html", the next ".../20190101-1500z.html". This goes from "...-0100z.html" to "...-2300z.html". After that the date is changing and the time is beginning again. Those are timestamps from the weather stations, when ever they are measuring the temperature.

Comment: Looking at the link you provided the HTML is a bit tricky, as it returns 7 readings on a single line. I also can't help but wonder if your approach is good in the first place. Here in the Netherlands we have a weather agency. You can download all historical measurements as CSV. If something similar would be available in Austria that would save you a lot of work.

Comment: Here in Austria there is the opportunity to download a CSV, but you can only get it by the end of the year or a few months later. This doesn't help me. So that's why I need to take this complicated approach.

Comment: It'd already be very helpful if I can get the code to insert all 7 readings into one cell. From there I can work with formulas.

Comment: Does your code work for each intended link? Also,do you intend to run this by supplying a start and end timestamp with some kind of interval/frequency?

Comment: I've tried it with multiple links and as far as I found out it is working every time. But I need to use two "getElementsByClassName", because the data is hidden behind two classes and those can differ from link to link. I also would like to define a start and end timestamp so I can get the information for a specific period.

Comment: would you retrieve for every hour for every day between a start and end date for example?

Comment: Exactly! For example: cell A1 = date (f.e. 20190101), cell b1 = time (if possible), cell c1 = data (all in one cell or if possible in the following cells of column c)

Comment: Aha... I understand it now. Is there a fixed max list of stations?

Comment: So, what I would do is have a tabular output that has date in one column, time in the next column then each of the stations one per column. Is this just temperature? If not answered by later this afternoon I will write something as this is quite a fun task and perfectly achievable (I think).

Comment: The stations can't be seen in the browser. There is just a map with the temperature. The exact temp. and the stations are in the source code.
If you change the time of day in the URL of my code example, you get the different stations with the updated temperatures.

Comment: It would be great if the date is in one column, time in the next, then the stations (those can be in different orders) in the next and then the temperature. For now it's just the temperature. I would like to get the same for humidity, but those are different URLs. I thank you very much!

Comment: Sure. Are the full list of stations given anywhere please?

Comment: There is no list on the website (at least what I know), but the stations are:
Wien-Mariabrunn (225m)
Wien-Hohe Warte (198m)
Wien-Unterlaa (200m)
Wien-Schwechat (183m)
Wien-Donaufeld (160m)
Grossenzersdorf (154m)
Wien-City (177m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works nicely for short date ranges. Longer date ranges lead to slower response. It is likely website is blocking/throttling. To this end:

1. I include a variable `pauseIndex` which means that every x (=pauseIndex) number  of urls, a delay of y seconds (as specified by `waitSeconds`) before the next request is added. You can play with this.
2. You might consider adapting code to run in daily/monthly batches and either append to bottom of existing dataset or write to a new sheet using the current day/month as title.
3. Perhaps rotate/change IPs and use `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`.

Tinker with the above to get the optimal settings and batch request size (if doing batch).

---

**Specifying start datetime and end datetimes:**

The date ranges are specified in a sheet called `Date ranges`. It has the following set-up:

[image]

---

**Building a dataset:**

I would recommend building a flat table dataset where you specify the exact stations to return info for. Not each station appears for every timedate.

```
stations = Array("Wien-Schwechat", "Wien-Unterlaa", "Wien-Mariabrunn", "Wien-Hohe Warte", "Grossenzersdorf", _
                     "Wien-Donaufeld", "Wien-City")
```

You can expand this. I include a dictionary variable `newStations` which stores all stations encountered that are not in your list for monitoring. You can easily write these out to help decide on additional stations to monitor/include in your dataset.

Placeholder values for missing station readings are used to ensure a complete dataset.

You may wish to normalise “outliers” - for example, actual hour values  can lie within the range rather than on the hour. In the demo below 16:20 is retrieved accurately for one station. You could normalise this to 16:00.

---

**Helper functions/Sub:**

There are a number of helper functions, and 1 sub, used in the code.

1. `GetAllLinks`. Generates all request urls between start date time and end date time. See notes within code. These can be looped to issue each request for data
2. `EmptyDict` - ensure that station data is cleared out between requests
3. `UpdateDictForNoReading`. Handles the case where a monitored station is not reported for specified datetime. It updates temperature and long station description with `"No reading"`
4. `WriteOutResults`. Produces a `"flat"` i.e. not nested, 2D array structure and writes results to specified output sheet

---

**Retrieving stations and station data:**

I use a css [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector, with `contains` operator, to target the station data.

Taking a example station's HTML

```html
<a class="ap o o-1 o-tmp--1" data-target="#obs-detail-3h" data-toggle="modal" data-left="635" data-top="545" onclick="obs_detail_3h('-1.0°C', 'Wien-Schwechat (183m)', '16:20','110360', '201901031500');" title="-1.0°C | Wien-Schwechat (183m) | 16:20" style="left: 408.533px; top: 337.757px;">-1</a>
```

If we look at the class attribute we see that is it as follows:

```
class="ap o o-1 o-tmp--1"
```

The value of the class attribute is `"ap o o-1 o-tmp--1"`, which is in fact a series of classes separated by spaces. Each station class value has the same substring which is `o-tmp`. You could vary this slightly. I use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to return a nodeList of all elements which have this substring in the class attribute value.

```
Set mapStations = html.querySelectorAll("[class*='o-tmp']")
```

This matches all stations on the page (map).

The `title` attribute of each node in the nodeList (`mapStations`) contains the data of interest:

```
title="-1.0°C | Wien-Schwechat (183m) | 16:20"
```

The string contains pipe (`|`) delimiters. I can use `split()` to generate an array containing each bit of info:

```
arr = Split(mapStations.item(i).Title, " | ")
```

That generates an array which will have `-1.0°C` ,  `Wien-Schwechat (183m)` and `16:20` at different indices. Using this example, I store `-1.0°C`  in variable `temp`, `Wien-Schwechat (183m)`  in variable `stationFull`, just the station name  `Wien-Schwechat`in `station`, `16:20` in `time`.

---

**TODO:**

1. Refactor to reduce level of nesting
2. Error handling for cases such as status code <> 200.....
3. Move variable declarations closer to their usage

---

**Requirements:**

1. VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library
2. Worksheet called `Date ranges`
3. Worksheet called `Output`

Data in `Date ranges` should be laid out as shown in image above.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    'VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    'Collect hourly temperature readings from list of stations in array stations.
    'Missing readings are populated with "Missing reading". Times specified in request are not necessarily identical _
    'to that correctly returned from page as reading reported within an hour interval may not be on the hour
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, i As Long, arr() As String, mapStations As Object, dict As Object, newStations As Object
    Dim time As String, station As String, temp As String, stations(), results(), j As Long
    Dim urls As Object, url As Variant, startOfDateString As Long, currDate As String, stationFull As String
    Dim outputSht As Worksheet, x As Long
    Const pauseIndex As Long = 20
    Const waitSeconds As Long = 1
    Const PREFIX As String = "https://kachelmannwetter.com/at/messwerte/wien/temperatur/"
    Const SUFFIX As String = "z.html"
    startOfDateString = InStrRev(PREFIX, "/") + 1
    Set outputSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")
    Set urls = GetAllLinks(PREFIX, SUFFIX)
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set newStations = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    stations = Array("Wien-Schwechat", "Wien-Unterlaa", "Wien-Mariabrunn", "Wien-Hohe Warte", "Grossenzersdorf", _
                     "Wien-Donaufeld", "Wien-City") 'order of stations here should match that in sheet
    j = 1

    For i = LBound(stations) To UBound(stations)
        dict(stations(i)) = vbNullString
    Next

    ReDim results(1 To 1 * urls.Count)

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        For Each url In urls
            x = x + 1
            If x Mod pauseIndex = 0 Then Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, waitSeconds)
            DoEvents
            .Open "GET", url, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

            Set mapStations = html.querySelectorAll("[class*='o-tmp']")

            For i = 0 To mapStations.Length - 1
                arr = Split(mapStations.item(i).Title, " | ")
                currDate = Join(Array(Mid$(url, startOfDateString + 4, 2), Mid$(url, startOfDateString + 6, 2), Mid$(url, startOfDateString, 4)), "-")
                temp = arr(0)
                station = Split(arr(1), " (")(0)
                stationFull = arr(1)
                time = arr(2)
                If Not dict.Exists(station) Then
                    newStations(station) = vbNullString 'in case you are interested in which stations exist you are not monitoring
                Else
                    dict(station) = Array(currDate, time, station, stationFull, temp)
                End If
            Next

            Set dict = UpdateDictForNoReading(dict, currDate, time)
            results(j) = dict.items
            j = j + 1
            Set dict = EmptyDict(dict)
        Next
    End With

    WriteOutResults outputSht, results, UBound(stations) + 1
End Sub

Public Function UpdateDictForNoReading(ByVal dict As Object, ByVal currDate As String, ByVal time As String) As Object
    'Loop dictionary containing station readings. If current value for key is not an array then no readings where found. _
    'then dict is updated with "No reading" for station long text (which includes m e.g. Wien-Schwechat (183m)) and temperature
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dict
        If Not IsArray(dict(key)) Then dict(key) = Array(currDate, time, key, "No reading", "No reading")
    Next
    Set UpdateDictForNoReading = dict
End Function

Public Sub WriteOutResults(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByRef results As Variant, ByVal stationCount As Long)
    'Loop results array which at each index should have a child array which is comprised of all stations specified _
    'The code unravels the nested structure into "flat" array for writing out to sheet. Aim is to be more efficient _
    'with writing out to sheet
    'The sheet to write results to is passed as argument ws. Headers are stated below.
    Dim headers(), outputArr(), i As Long, arr(), j As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    headers = Array("Date", "Time", "Station", "StationFull", "Temp")
    ReDim outputArr(1 To UBound(results) * stationCount, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

    For i = LBound(results) To UBound(results)
        arr = results(i)                         '0-6
        For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            r = r + 1
            If IsArray(arr(j)) Then
                For c = LBound(arr(j)) To UBound(arr(j))
                    outputArr(r, c + 1) = arr(j)(c)
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(outputArr, 1), UBound(outputArr, 2)) = outputArr
    End With
End Sub

Public Function EmptyDict(ByVal dict As Object) As Object
    'Ensures no data remains from prior request
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dict
        dict(key) = vbNullString
    Next
    Set EmptyDict = dict
End Function

Public Function GetAllLinks(ByVal PREFIX As String, ByVal SUFFIX As String) As Object
    'Generate all urls between start date time and end date time. Accounts for fact that there is no real midnight. 00:00 uhr retrieves the 23:00 of prior day.
    'Times selected on page e.g. 1:00 uhr are one hour ahead of what is used in url string e.g. 1 > 0.
    Dim ws As Worksheet, hours(), urls As Collection

    Set urls = New Collection
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Date ranges")
    'url "0000" = 1am. The selection of 00:00 in the sheet gives 23:00 of prior date
    hours = Array("0000", "0100", "0200", "0300", "0400", "0500", "0600", "0700", "0800", "0900", "1000", "1100", "1200", _
                  "1300", "1400", "1500", "1600", "1700", "1800", "1900", "2000", "2100", "2200", "2300")

    Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date, startTime As String, endTime As String, currentDate As Date
    Dim endIndex As Long, startIndex As Long

    With ws
        startDate = .Cells(1, 2).Value2          'Required for input yyyy-mm-dd; Required for output yyyymmdd
        endDate = .Cells(1, 5).Value2
        startTime = .Cells(2, 2)
        endTime = .Cells(2, 5)
    End With

    startIndex = Application.Match(startTime, hours) - 2
    endIndex = Application.Match(endTime, hours) - 2
    currentDate = startDate

    Dim i As Long, s As Long, e As Long

    Do While currentDate <= endDate
        If startDate = endDate Then
            s = startIndex
            e = endIndex
        Else
            Select Case currentDate
            Case startDate
                s = startIndex
                e = UBound(hours)
            Case endDate
                s = LBound(hours)
                e = endIndex
            Case Else
                s = LBound(hours)
                e = UBound(hours)
            End Select
        End If
        For i = s To e
            urls.Add PREFIX & Format$(currentDate, "yyyymmdd") & "-" & hours(i) & SUFFIX
        Next
        currentDate = DateAdd("d", 1, currentDate)

    Loop
    Set GetAllLinks = urls
End Function
```

---

**Example output:**

[image]

Comment: For humidity same code but use the following selector instead [class*='o-lf']